# Subscribe to email

Tags: plugin-recommendation, email, updates, subscription

I am looking for a way where, the users of my website will subscribe to a post, and when my post will be edited or updated they will be emailed by my posts contents,

My post contains, article, Twitter Updates, a Video
How will the users get notification when my posts get updated and also when someone comments on posts

Comment: Are you manually updating the posts content or is the content updated automatically by some plugins, webservices etc.?

Comment: @hakre Its automatic, the video gets updated through youtube, twitter updates get updates, content I will be updating manually

Comment: I'm not sure if something for automatic updates is available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this two plugins:

1. [Post Notification](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/post-notification/)
2. [Subscribe2](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/subscribe2/)

Comment: Are these personal recommendations? Post Notification only lists support upto 2.7.

Comment: http://pn.xn--strbe-mva.de/forum.php?req=thread&id=599, here reports 3.0.1

Comment: will it also email if I update the published post?

Answer (score 1):

[Subscribe2](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/subscribe2/) works well for what you need. Just insert the **[subscribe2]** shortcode wherever you need a signup form.

If you want it to email after edits, try saving it to draft first before publishing. I believe that might be necessary to trigger the email event.

Answer (score 0):

simple you can use any plugin to send update of your site also you can check my site for guide [**braincuber technologies**](https://www.braincuber.com)

Comment: I don't see a guide for this on your site? Even if there was though, we prefer answers here to stand alone: could you write a complete answer here instead of linking us to an off-site answer please?